# How to find priori information in Cramer Rao Lower Bound when the pdf of the parameter is unkown

Tags: communication, signal-processing, telecommunications

In order to compute a Bayesian Cramer Rao Lower bound, we need to find
the prior information of a random parameter "theta" which is a complex
scalar parameter. The pdf of "theta" is f( . ).

Prior information = $$\mathbb{E}\left\{\left[\dfrac{\partial 
\ln(f(\theta))}{\partial \theta}\right]^*\left[\dfrac{\partial 
\ln(f(\theta))}{\partial \theta}\right]\right\}$$

It is given that the joint characteristic function of
$$\theta=\theta_r+j \theta_i$$ is given by
$$\phi_{\theta_r,\theta_i}(\omega_1,\omega_2) = 
\dfrac{1}{\left(1+\dfrac{\omega_1^2+\omega_2^2}{4}a^2\right)^n}$$
where \$a\$ is a known constant.

Is there any way (numerical or analytical) to find the prior
information?

I am able to find the marginal pdf of \$\theta_r\$ and \$\theta_i\$ via
inverse transform, but not their joint pdf which is required to find the
prior information.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might be better suited to [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com).